# Find the equation of the tangent to a system using implicit function theorem

Tags: systems-of-equations, differential, tangent-line, implicit-function-theorem

Here is my system of equations:

$C: \begin{cases}x^2 + y^2 +z^2 = 14\\ x^3+y^3+z^3=36 \end{cases}$

Firstly I managed to show that for all  $a \in C$, the implicit function theorem applies to express $x$ and $y$ as a function of $z$. Which implies the existence of $\phi$ such that, for all $(x,y,z)$ close enough to $a$, we get:

$f(x,y,z)=0 \Leftrightarrow \phi(z) = (x,y)$

(with f being the function: $f(x,y,z) = (x^2+y^2+z^2-14, x^3+y^3+z^3-36)$

What I do not undesrstand is how to find the equation of the tangent at the point $(1,2,3) \in C$.

What I had done was to start from the realtion given by the theorem: $f(\phi(z),z)=0$

By deriving both sides, I get: $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x \partial y}(\frac{\partial\phi(z)}{\partial z},z) \circ \frac{\partial\phi(z)}{\partial z} + \frac{\partial f(\phi(z),z)}{\partial z} = 0$

Which I rearrange:

$\frac{\partial\phi(z)}{\partial z} = \frac{\partial f^{-1}}{\partial x \partial y}(\frac{\partial\phi(z)}{\partial z},z) \circ \frac{\partial f(\phi(z),z)}{\partial z}$

If this is anywhere near to the anwser, where do I plug the values $(1,2,3)$ in?

Comment: Being polynomial, we can write the equations about the point by translating to the origin and back $$\begin{align}(x-1)^2+(y-2)^2+(z-3)^2+2(x-1)+4(y-2)+6(z-3)&=0\\
(x-1)^3+(y-2)^3+(z-3)^3+3(x-1)^2+6(y-2)^2+9(z-3)^2+3(x-1)+12(y-2)+27(z-3)&=0\end{align}$$ cut the higher order terms, and intersect the tangent cones. $$\begin{align}&2(x-1)+4(y-2)+6(z-3)&=0\\
\quad\quad\quad\quad&3(x-1)+12(y-2)+27(z-3)&=0\end{align}$$ Now it's linear algebra: $$\begin{align}(x-1)-3(z-3)&=0\\(y-2)+3(z-3)&=0\\ (z-3)-(z-3)&=0\end{align}$$ And letting $(z-3)=t$ $$\begin{align}x&=1+3t\\ y&=2-3t\\z&=3+t\end{align}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your system in a neighbourhood of the point $P=(1,2,3)$ defines a differentiable curve $\gamma$. By using the Implicit Function Theorem, we may find the tangent line to $\gamma$ at $P$: there exist two functions $x=\phi(z)$ and $y=\psi(z)$ such that $\phi(3)=1$ and $\psi(3)=2$ and the desired tangent line has the following parametric equation:
$$\begin{cases} 
x=1+\phi'(3)t\\
y=2+\psi'(3)t\\
z=3+t\end{cases}$$
You may find $\phi'(3)$ and $\psi'(3)$, by deriving the equations in the system with respect to $z$ and solving it:
$$\begin{cases}\phi(z)^2 + \psi(z)^2 +z^2 = 14\\ \phi(z)^3+\psi(z)^3+z^3=36 \end{cases}
\implies
\begin{cases}
2\cdot 1\cdot \phi'(3) + 2\cdot 2\cdot \psi'(3) +2\cdot 3 = 0\\  3\cdot 1^2\cdot \phi'(3) + 3\cdot 2^2\cdot \psi'(3) +3\cdot 3^2 = 0 \end{cases}$$
Can you take it from here?
[image]

Comment: This sounds better: I get $\phi'(3)$ = 3 and $\psi'(3)$ = -3

Comment: Yes, now you are correct. Well done!

Comment: thank you so much for your help!

Comment: The graph you sent looks awesome! What tool do you use ? :)

Comment: Desmos 3D: see https://www.desmos.com/3d/993989ce2a